# how to share an android project with sourcetree and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm having a lot of problems with sharing a android project using sourcetree and eclipse. 
I have tried the following:
- First importing the git from sourcetree and afterwards importing this in eclipse
- Creating empty project in eclipse and then try to import to it throught git/sourcetree.

It seems like no matter how I try to do it, it doesn't do it right. Some of the attempts, I have duplicated projects (which is created by eclipse twice, I dont know why)

Anyway, can anyone give an explanation on how to import a project from git so that I can see the changes in eclipse and push/pull/commit in the source tree?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clone your project with sourcetree on your Desktop (e.g) then add your project to Eclipse
Right click on the Package Explorer -> Import -> in Android -> "Existing Android Code Into Workspace" -> Select your folder project then click Finish.

You can also copy the project to your workspace by selecting the checkbox.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much :) But can I delete the project on the desktop after importing it to eclipse?

Comment: If you checked the option Copy in WorkSpace while importing, then **yes**, a new copy will be created in your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I zip the project folder.
I then extract it on another computer and import the project in Eclipse again...
Easy, isn't it?