# sourcetree and eclipse - can't pull from git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have some problems with a git repository. The main problem is that I can't pull from it, but i am still able to push to it. 
I had some problems when I wanted to import it in eclipse, but got it to work after my previous question [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497518/how-to-share-an-android-project-with-sourcetree-and-eclipse/20498096?noredirect=1#20498096) .

I can pull from the git repo if I delete the repository in sourcetree and the project in eclipse and then import it again, but obviously I don't want to do that every time I wish to pull.

I really hope anyone can understand my problem and hopefully have some suggestions for a solution

Comment: do you get any sort of error message when you pull?

Comment: nope I dont get anything. Usually there is a mark, on the "pull" icon, when there is something to pull, but not in this case. And when I click it, nothing happends

Comment: Try to do it from the command line. Might be something that you can't see in the UI.